# Change the order of integration:$\int_{0}^{1} dx \int_{0}^{1}dy \int_{0}^{x^2+y^2}f(x,y,z)dz$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, analysis

$$\int_{0}^{1} dx \int_{0}^{1}dy \int_{0}^{x^2+y^2}f(x,y,z)dz$$

in the order : $$\int dz \int dx \int f(x,y,z)dy$$ I don't think it needs to be divided into two seperate integrals, but the professor did, and i do not know why?

Comment: It should be divided into two. Use [my method](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1220985/change-the-order-of-integrals-int-01dx-int-01-xdy-int-0xyfx-y-zdz) again, and note $z>x^2$ and $z<x^2$ will be different.

Comment: Could you perhaps type it out because i think there is a mistake in my book? Am i really want to see where to devide the integrals..

Comment: Why not try to show us the answer you get?

Comment: I will, right after i eat..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the following picture:

[image]

When integrating with respect to $y$, only the shaded region is from $0$ to $1$. The other part is from the surface to $1$.